# Is there any tool to check if js file is safe to compress?

Tags: javascript, debugging, compression, minify

Sometimes it happens that one missing character in a huge js file ruins the whole minification magic. Is there any tool that can check if js file can be compressed without errors prior to compression itself and of course point out where that potential problem is.

Comment: You should find out what specifically is causing the problem with compression, and maybe you can find a way to fix it yourself.

Comment: Compression should *never* change the behavior of code. That said, all compressors have bugs -- but most of the popular ones are very robust and should be safe to use on even very large projects. I recommend the Closure Compiler as Google uses it themselves on some huge sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than simply validating your code, it's better to use a tool that helps you keep your code clean and organized.

[JSLint](http://jslint.com/) and [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) can both be used to help keep your code clean. If it's clean, it'll work in a minifier.